# Check if several booleans have the same value

Tags: c#, boolean, compare

I have three boolean variables. I need to check if all three are true or all three are false.

I can do this in a 'dummy' way:

```
bool areSame = false; 
if(a && b && c)    
    areSame = true; 
else if (!a && !b && !c)
    areSame = true;
```

I'd like to know if there is another more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the equality operator on booleans too:

```
bool areSame = (a == b) && (a == c);
```

Comment: Why settle for readable code when you can throw in bitwise operands instead? `var areSame = !(a ^ b | b ^ c);` :D

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I sometimes go for bitwise operations for efficiency (e.g. to multiply or divide by powers of 2), but I doubt there will be any performance benefits here.

Comment: yeah, I was just joking around anyway.  There's no way I'd use bitwise operations for a simple check like this.  If it was just to check that all values were `true` then I'd say "go to it!" with `bool areSame = a & b & c & d & e` but the all `false` option kinda throws a monkey wrench into that.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you're only comparing three here, but what about ***the future***? You might have to compare ten booleans to each other somewhere down the road.

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(false.AllEqual(false, false)); 
                Console.WriteLine(true.AllEqual(false, false));
                Console.WriteLine(true.AllEqual(true, false));

                bool a = true;
                bool b = false;
                bool c = true;
                Console.WriteLine(a.AllEqual(b, c));
                b = true;
                Console.WriteLine(a.AllEqual(b, c));
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 
        }

        static class Extensions
    {
        static public  bool AllEqual(this bool firstValue, params bool[] bools)
        {
            return bools.All(thisBool => thisBool == firstValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're right. And the answer is really great. But in right now it's not likely this will be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

how about using this?

```
areSame = (a == b && b == c);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
bool areSame = (a && b && c) || (!a && !b && !c) ? true : false;
```

Comment: This smth like if(true == true), which is tautology.

Comment: It might be a little verbose (I'm not sure of C# syntax), but it's not tautological — it's if (true) then true else false, not if (true == true)

Comment: @anotherdave you are both correct. It is verbose and tautological. The ternary conditional vs output can be understood as identical.  In C#, conditionals must always be boolean so `bool y = x ? true : false;` is the same as `var y = (bool)x` and `bool y = x;` thus `bool areSame = (a && b && c) || (!a && !b && !c) ? true : false;` is the same as `bool areSame = (a && b && c) || (!a && !b && !c);` in every possible interpretation (even considering operator overloading, short-circuiting and `implicit` type conversions). `a == b == c;` is the less verbose and easier to understand alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach? It will allow you to pass in as many bools and see if the min number of trues are met.

```
public static bool AreMinNumberOfTruesMet(int minNumOftrue, params bool[] bools)
{
    var totalTrue = bools.Count(boolean => boolean == true);

    return totalTrue >= minNumOftrue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in one line :

```
bool allSame = !bools.Any(b => b != bools[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//all same
bool allSame = a == b == c == d;

//all false
bool allFalse = a == b == c == d == false;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This assertion fails: `bool allSame = true == false == false == true; Debug.Assert(!allSame);` The four booleans `true`, `false`, `false` and `true` are not the same, so the assertion `!allSame` should succeed.